# MySQL - Replace string when it appears

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

The column 'PrizeMoneyBreakDown' includes a number of strings seperated by a semi-colon. I am trying to remove the strings 'total value', 'trophy total value', and 'welfare fund' from the data. These strings only appear sometimes in the data so it is not as simple as just removing the last three strings. I need to write a query that removes the strings **IF** they appear.

Example of data:

```
1st,5285;2nd,1680;3rd,885;4th,550;5th,350;6th,350;7th,350;8th,350;total_value,10000;welfare_fund,200;trophy_total_value,150;
```

Desired output of data:

```
1st,5285;2nd,1680;3rd,885;4th,550;5th,350;6th,350;7th,350;8th,350
```

Current code (only removes the words 'total value' etc - does not remove prize money associated with string):

```
SELECT PrizeMoneyBreakDown,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PrizeMoneyBreakDown,'total_value',""),'welfare_fund',""),'trophy_total_value',"") as new
FROM race2;
```

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrizeMoneyBreakDown, ';total_value,', 1), ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT PrizeMoneyBreakDown,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(PrizeMoneyBreakDown,
                      '(total_value|welfare_fund|trophy_total_value),\\d+;',
                      '') AS NewPrizeMoneyBreakDown
FROM race2;
```

If you want to *update* the actual column then use:

```sql
UPDATE race2
SET PrizeMoneyBreakDown = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    PrizeMoneyBreakDown,
    '(total_value|welfare_fund|trophy_total_value),\\d+;',
    '')
WHERE PrizeMoneyBreakDown REGEXP '(total_value|welfare_fund|trophy_total_value),\\d+;';
```

Comment: This did not work. It didn't even remove the words 'total_value'.

Comment: @kjdcwckj Sorry...you need `\\d+` for a number, not `\d+`, please try it again.

Comment: How do I replace the old column 'PrizeMoneyBreakdown' with the new column in the table race2